# NodeJS: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, scope, electron

### The Problem

I'm working with Electron and Node, and am having issues where a variable (`this.mainWindow`) is only accessible inside of the function it was created in. Whenever an event listener fires, `this.mainWindow` is undefined. This is all occurring inside of a class, so `this` should be a reference to the working instance of that class, correct?

### The Code

```
class AppManager {

    constructor (app, options) {
        this.app = app
        this.options = options = {}
        this.bindEvents()
    }

    bindEvents () {
        this.app.on('ready', this.onReady.bind(this))
        this.app.on('window-all-closed', this.onWindowAllClosed.bind(this))
        this.app.on('activate', this.onActivate.bind(this))
    }

    onReady () {
        this.createWindow()
    }

    onWindowAllClosed () {
        if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
            this.app.quit()
        }
    }

    onActivate () {
        if (this.app.mainWindow === null) {
            this.createWindow()
        }
    }

    onClose (e) {
    // here, this.mainWindow and this.isQuitting are undefined.
        if (this.isQuiting) {
            this.mainWindow = null
        } else {
            e.preventDefault()
            this.mainWindow.hide()
        }
    }

    onClick () {
        // here, this.mainWindow is undefined.
        this.mainWindow.show()
    }

    createWindow () {
    // here, we declare this.isQuitting
        this.isQuitting = false

        this.contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
            {
                label: 'Show App',
                click: function () {
                    this.mainWindow.show()
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Quit',
                click: function () {
                    this.isQuiting = true
                    this.app.quit()
                }
            }
        ])

        this.tray = new Tray('./public/images/icon.ico')
        this.tray.setContextMenu(this.contextMenu)
        this.tray.on('click', this.onClick)

        // at this point, we assign the variable mainWindow to "this".
        this.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(this.options)
        this.mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../../../public/index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }))
        this.mainWindow.tray = this.tray
        this.mainWindow.on('close', this.onClose)
    }
}
```

### The Error

`A JavaScript error occurred in the main process`
`Uncaught exception: TypeError: cannot read property hide of undefined`

The error occurs when I close the window, or click on the tray icon. That is when `onClose` and `onClick` fire, and that is when `this.mainWindow` and `this.isQuitting` are `undefined`

Let me know if you'd like more information.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

you are passing `this.onClose`, but you are probably losing the reference to `this`.

```
this.mainWindow.on('close', this.onClose.bind(this));
```

Should fix it.